# How can I include a Filter Criteria which includes a )

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA code to filter a field that has Pack Sizes ... the pack size format could be (Pack of 1), (Pack of 2)... If I fiter on Pack of 1 then this would pick up Pack of 1, Pack of 10, Pack of 100 etc.... so I need to incude the ) in the filter...  The code I have below does not retunr any values from the filter... is there a way to incorporate the ) in the filter statement...

```
Sub Create_Amazon_Pack_Info()
Dim AmzDataWs As Worksheet
Set AmzDataWs = Sheets("Amazon Data")

Dim PackListWs As Worksheet 
Set PackListWs = Sheets("Pack Lists")

Dim PackListTbl As ListObject
Set PackListTbl = PackListWs.ListObjects("PL_Table")

Dim AmzPackDtaWs As Worksheet
Set AmzPackDtaWs = Sheets("Amazon Pack Data")

Dim ApdTbl As ListObject
Set ApdTbl = AmzDataWs.ListObjects("APD_Table")

Dim PackSizeCount As Long

'=====================================================================================
 'Ensure Filteris reset
 
   With PackListTbl
    If .ShowAutoFilter Then
        If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
 End With
 
'Get ast row in Pack List Table
PackSizeCount = PackListTbl.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

'ForEach Pack Type Filter Amazon Data and Set Pack Size

ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Pack of 1)"
```

End Sub

Comment: `Criteria1:="*Pack of 1)"` ?  Or maybe `Criteria1:="*Pack of 1)*"` if there's other text in that field.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria1:="*Pack of 1)*" worked

Comment: If so, which is the purpose of your question? Is it anything else not working?

Comment: The answer that was given by Tim Williams solved it for me - I am having other issue now but will raise a new question

Comment: `Criteria1:="Pack of 1)"` is what was in your original question.  Tims answer had the `*` in it.